# add color tint in image hover in jquery + css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this button which has a jquery image hover.
How could I add a css color tint overlay to the image when the button is hovered.
is this possible?

here's my attempt, i added a background-color to mouseover event in my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxLength = 120;
  $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
      $(this).empty().html(newStr);
      $(this).append('<center><button class="btnsvc" name="wwdimg" style="top:20px" href="#!">Learn More</button></center>');
    }
  });

    $('button[name="wwdimg"]').ready(function(){
        $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(10%)"});
    });
    $('button[name="wwdimg"]').mouseover(function(){
        $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(80%)","background-color":"orange"});

    });
      $('button[name="wwdimg"]').mouseout(function(){
        $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(10%)"});
    });


});


<div class="content back">
<img name="img_holder" src="http://192.168.1.250/sopi2018/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/h_backoffice-300x300.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-604" /> 

   <div class="show-read-more">Content and Creative Writing, Social Media Management, SEO, Outbound Sales, Outbound Sales Appointment Setting, Inbound sales, Surveys, Vendor Management and Support, Virtual Assistants    
</div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yh9L/604/

Comment: you could create a second div for the overlay and position it over the button with an opacity value

Comment: i need to be in jquery not in html.

Comment: your code works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/4yh9L/610/

Comment: I need a color tint on top of my image. how could i do that?

Comment: @user3117337 it still would be, just on click remove class hidden from overlay

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped your `img` tag in a `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxLength = 120;
  $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
 var myStr = $(this).text();
 if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
   var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
   var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
   $(this).empty().html(newStr);
   $(this).append('<center><button class="btnsvc" name="wwdimg" style="top:20px" href="#!">Learn More</button></center>');
 }
  });

 $('button[name="wwdimg"]').ready(function(){
  $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(10%)"});
 });
 $('button[name="wwdimg"]').mouseover(function(){
  $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(80%)"});
  $('.img-block').addClass('active');
  
 });
 $('button[name="wwdimg"]').mouseout(function(){
  $('img[name="img_holder"]').css({"opacity": "1","filter":"brightness(10%)"});
  $('.img-block').removeClass('active');
 });


});
```

```css
.img-block {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.img-block:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.active.img-block:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.img-block img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content back">
  <div class="img-block">
          <img name="img_holder" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-604" /> 
        </div>
        <div class="show-read-more">
         Content and Creative Writing, Social Media Management, SEO, Outbound Sales, Outbound Sales Appointment Setting, Inbound sales, Surveys, Vendor Management and Support, Virtual Assistants    
        </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there anyway i can inject everything in jquery not in css?

Comment: @user3117337 See here you need to have tint for `img` and img cant have background  or `pseudo elements`.So that should be done with help of another div and some css tricks :)